# How can I get output in and out of grep from within a C program?

Tags: c, grep, pipe, posix

I wrote the following code. It spawns a `grep`, connects its input and output to some pipes, and sends in some text. Then it tries to read the output. When I run it, I see no output from grep.

1. If I comment out the second `dup2` (no longer redirecting grep's output), I see its output in the terminal.
2. If I use a different program from grep (say `cat -`), I see the expected output.

I've heard some programs buffer their output differently when they know their output isn't connected to a terminal, but then how come things like `echo hello | grep hello | cat` work on the command line? Does the console somehow fool grep into thinking `cat` is a terminal?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

struct Pipe
{
    int read;
    int write;
};

struct Pipe main2grep;
struct Pipe grep2main;

int main()
{
    pipe((int*) &main2grep);
    pipe((int*) &grep2main);

    char *arguments[4];
    arguments[0] = "grep";
    arguments[1] = "apples";
    arguments[2] = 0;

    int result = fork();
    if (result == 0)
    {
        dup2(main2grep.read, STDIN_FILENO);
        dup2(grep2main.write, STDOUT_FILENO);

        execvp(arguments[0], arguments);
        return 0;
    }

    char *input = "apples\n";
    int write_result = write(main2grep.write, input, 7);
    printf("wrote %d bytes to %s\n", write_result, arguments[0]);
    close(main2grep.write);
    
    int pid = result;
    char buffer[128];
    while (1)
    {
        int n_read = read(grep2main.read, buffer, 128);
        if (n_read != -1)
        {
            buffer[n_read] = 0;
            printf("from grep: %s\n", buffer);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Probably `popen()`. You're effectively re-writing that built-in function yourself right here.

Comment: It might help to add grep's option `--line-buffered`. See `man grep`.

Comment: It does work with `--line-buffered`, but that's not really the point - grep works fine without that in bash scripts, in the terminal etc, so I should be able to make my program work that way too. `popen()` is not quite suitable for my use case because it invokes `sh`, but in any case I'd like to understand what's happening anyway.

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but as a side note, spawning a child `grep` process and parsing its output is probably overkill for what you're trying to do -- it would be less programming work and more runtime-efficient to simply `#include <regex.h>` and then use `regcomp()` to compile a regular expression object followed by a call to `regexec()` for each line of text, to test whether that line of text matches the expression or not.  (Then `regfree()` at the end to clean up)

Answer (score 0):

I believe what's happening is that when you run something like `echo hello | grep hello`, the `echo` process *ends* - and grep receives an EOF (more precisely, grep calls `read` and gets back zero bytes). grep seems to be programmed to flush its output automatically when it gets an EOF.

In the amended code, I call `close` on the write end of the main-to-grep pipe. Make sure to do this from *both* processes, parent and child, because the kernel only sends EOF when all open file handles are closed. Of course, in the parent process you should only close the pipe after sending your data.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

struct Pipe
{
    int read;
    int write;
};

struct Pipe main2grep;
struct Pipe grep2main;

int main()
{
    pipe((int*) &main2grep);
    pipe((int*) &grep2main);

    char *arguments[4];
    arguments[0] = "grep";
    arguments[1] = "apples";
    arguments[2] = 0;

    int result = fork();
    if (result == 0)
    {
        dup2(main2grep.read, STDIN_FILENO);
        dup2(grep2main.write, STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(main2grep.write);
        close(grep2main.read);

        execvp(arguments[0], arguments);
        return 0;
    }

    char *input = "apples\n";
    int write_result = 0;
    write_result += write(main2grep.write, input, 7);
    printf("wrote %d bytes to %s\n", write_result, arguments[0]);
    close(main2grep.write);
    
    int pid = result;
    char buffer[128];
    while (1)
    {
        int n_read = read(grep2main.read, buffer, 128);
        if (n_read != -1)
        {
            buffer[n_read] = 0;
            printf("from grep: %s\n", buffer);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should probably avoid the expression "sends EOF".  EOF is not something that is "sent".  When all of the writing sides of a pipe are closed, then a `read` on the pipe will return EOF, but the EOF was not something that was on the pipe.  It's a pre-processor symbol used as the return value from `read` to indicate that no more data is available.  It's not "sent" by anything.  It's just the name for the value returned by `read`.